# JavaScript RunTime Error : appendChild() - Unexpected call to method or property in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom, runtime-error, appendchild

I am getting runtime JS error like : "Unexpected call to method or property".
Here is the code :

```
    var comboInput = document.getElementById("Combo");
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.value = "-1";
    option1.innerHTML = "--Select--";
    comboInput.appendChild(option1); //At this line debugger breaks and
                                     // throws the above error
```

I gone through some of similar questions on SO about this issue but still not getting the solution.

Please help..
Thanks in adv...

Comment: try to see what `comboInput` have. or will u please paste the relevant code

Comment: The value of comboInput is : 

`ObjectHTMLinputElement`

Comment: Input elements are always self-closing and can't have children, as far as I know. It sounds like you actually want `#Combo` to be a [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select) element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append children to `<input>` elements.

`<option>` elements can only be children of `<select>` elements, where `<select>` elements are html's version of a drop-down list (or a multiselect list depending on the attributes you give it).

Try changing your html so that your "Combo" element is like this:

```
<select id="Combo"></select>
```

and then your code should work.

Note though that you can set options directly in the html markup, e.g.,

```
<select id="Combo">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Purple</option>
</select>
```

(And having put options in your html you can add additional options and/or remove options via JS.)

Comment: Seems right but its perfectly working in FF/Chrome.

However thanks for correcting...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check on the value of `comboInput` (output its value with `console.log()` or in an `alert()` to see what it's set to).

It likely has a value of `null` because your code didn't find an existing object with `id="Combo"`.  This can be because:

1. Such an object doesn't exist in your page
2. You didn't get the id exactly right
3. You're running this code before the page has loaded so the object hasn't yet been loaded/created.

If you include the entire page context (all HTML and all JS or a link to a live page), we could tell you more specifically what steps should be taken to correct the issue.

Comment: I checked in the page.Combo exist in it. See the below code :
`<input id="Combo" type="hidden"/>`

Comment: Op said error in IE8 and i think `console.log` will generate error in IE. isn't it so?

Comment: I didn't use console.log but directly alert the elem's value

Comment: The IE8 debugger supports `console.log()`.  You just have to have the debugger open for it to be supported.

Comment: @adn295 - what browser are you running this code in?  It does appear that you should be adding option tags as children of a select tag, not an input tag.